# Positive correlation with the sequence $\sqrt{ij}/2-\min(i,j)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, positive-definite

Is there a sequence of positive real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ for which
$$
\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\left[\frac{\sqrt{ij}}{2}-\min(i,j)\right]x_ix_j> 0?
$$

Comment: Checked manually for a few small $n$. All eigenvalues are negative, so no, there is no such sequence for these $n$. Coincidence? I don't think so...

Comment: So you think that $(\min(i,j))\succ (\sqrt{ij}/2)$?

Comment: I don't even know what does $\succ$ mean in this context.

Comment: For matrices $X\succ Y$ means that $X-Y$ is positive definite. Here I've written the matrices componentwise.

Comment: @IvanNeretin not a coincidence, see answer below

Comment: You didn't double-check, huh ? ; +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution:

There exists such $n$ and a sequence of positive real numbers $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$.

Let $A$ denote the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\frac{\sqrt{ij}}{2}$.
Then, $A = uu^\mathsf{T}$ where
$u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{2}, \cdots, \sqrt{n}]^\mathsf{T}$.

Let $B$ denote the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\min(i, j)$.
Note that $B^{-1}$ is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix of the form
\begin{align}
B^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 2 & -1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 2 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 2 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
(Note: The diagonal entries are $2, 2, \cdots, 2, 1$. The subdiagonal and superdiagonal entries are all $-1$. )

Let $v = B^{-1}u$.

*Fact 1*: $v_i > 0$ for $i=1, 2, \cdots, n$.

*Fact 2*: $u^\mathsf{T}B^{-1}u = \frac{n^2}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)}$.

*Fact 3*: $v^\mathsf{T}(A - B)v = (u^\mathsf{T}B^{-1}u)^2 - u^\mathsf{T}B^{-1}u$.

The proofs are easy and thus omitted.

Now, from Facts 1, 2, 3, if $u^\mathsf{T}B^{-1}u > 1$ or equivalently $\frac{n^2}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)} > 1$, then $v^\mathsf{T}(A - B)v > 0$.
It is easy to prove that there exists $n$ such that $\frac{n^2}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)} > 1$.
Indeed, by using
$\sqrt{k(k+1)} \le k + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{16k}$ for $k \ge 1$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)} \le \frac{n^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$
which results in
$$\frac{n^2}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)} \ge \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{16}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}.$$
The desired result follows.

For such $n$ and $v$, we have
$$\sum_{1\le i, j\le n} \left[\frac{\sqrt{ij}}{2} - \min(i, j)\right] v_iv_j = v^\mathsf{T}(A - B)v > 0.$$

Remark: Denote $F(n) = \frac{n^2}{2} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sqrt{k(k+1)}$. By Maple, $F(55) = 0.99974443 < 1$ and $F(56) = 1.00199623$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes". Consider the matrix $A_n=[a_{ij}]_{1\le i,j\le n}$, defined by

$$ a_{ij} = \min(i,j) - \frac{\sqrt{ij}}2. $$

As mentioned in a comment, this is positive definite for small $n$, but it turns out not to be the case always. Since the $k^\text{th}$ minor of $A_n$ is simply $A_k$, [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) implies that $A_n$ being positive definite is equivalent to $\det(A_k) > 0$ for $k\le n$. By implementing the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np

def special_matrix(n):
    '''Define the matrix A_n'''
    matrix = np.identity(n)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            matrix[i,j] = min(i+1,j+1) - np.sqrt((i+1)*(j+1)) / 2
            # Note we use i+1, j+1 since Python indexes starting at 0
    return matrix

for n in range(2,100):
    if np.linalg.det(special_matrix(n)) < 0:
        print(n)
        break

>>> 56
```

we see that $\det(A_n) \ge 0$ for $n < N:= 56$, and $\det(A_N) < 0$. This means $A_N$ is *not* positive definite. In particular, $A_N$ has a negative eigenvalue. If this eigenvalue has a corresponding positive eigenvector $\mathbf x = (x_1,\ldots,x_N)$, then clearly this will provide the desired sequence. We then implement the following code:

```
N = 56

Matrix = special_matrix(N)

evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(Matrix)

for i in range(N):
    if evals[i] <= 0:
        evec = -evecs[:,i]
        # Negate the eigenvector, since by default it returns an eigenvector 
        # with all negative entries
        print(evec)
        break

>>> [0.97135177 0.17110863 0.08503891 0.05411931 0.03839335 0.02907463
 0.02301033 0.018801   0.01573758 0.01342565 0.0116299  0.01020206
 0.00904451 0.00809062 0.00729348 0.00661925 0.00604291 0.00554566
 0.00511308 0.00473398 0.00439953 0.0041027  0.00383783 0.00360028
 0.00338627 0.00319267 0.00301683 0.00285657 0.00271002 0.00257558
 0.0024519  0.00233782 0.00223232 0.00213452 0.00204366 0.00195907
 0.00188016 0.00180641 0.00173736 0.0016726  0.00161176 0.00155453
 0.0015006  0.00144973 0.00140166 0.00135619 0.00131313 0.0012723
 0.00123355 0.00119672 0.00116169 0.00112834 0.00109669 0.00107966
 0.00226057 0.11233599]
```

We have found a positive eigenvector $\mathbf x$, so it provides the desired sequence. Let us double check that this really does make the desired sum positive:

```
desired_sum = 0
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        desired_sum += (np.sqrt((i+1)*(j+1)) / 2 - min(i+1,j+1))*evec[i]*evec[j]
        # Note again the use of i+1 and j+1
print(desired_sum)

>>> 0.011233898661515196
```

confirming our answer.

Note that, since we also incidentally demonstrated that such a sequence cannot have length shorter than $56$, it seems unlikely that there will be a nice analytic (i.e. non-numerical) solution to this problem.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood my answer. There is indeed a solution, for $n=56$. But I didn't prove it, I asked a computer. A proof would involve finding a negative eigenvalue of $A_n$ which has a strictly positive eigenvector, and the usual way of finding positive eigenvectors (Perron-Frobenius) is of no help. Additionally, any argument involves letting $n\to\infty$ would need to make sure all the limits are strictly positive, not just non-negative. It's probably not impossible, but it seems more difficult than the numerical approach (maybe I should have said "simple" instead of "nice").

Comment: huh. someone deleted my comment. anyways, see the other solution; looks like you were indeed proven wrong (as i suspected)